# Elements of an specific order in a non cyclic non abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

I've got a non cyclic non abelian group G = < (1 2 3 4 5),(2 5)(3 4) > which is a subgroups of S_5 and the order of G is 10.
And my question is: Is there any element of order 4 in G?

---

What I have done is:
Firstly, if H is a subgroup of G, the order of H has to be 1,2,5 or 10. But now, can I suppose that H is going to be cyclic? or maybe H is not cyclic? I dont't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of every element $g$ of some group $G$ (which equals the order of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ of $G$ generated by $g$) divides the order of $G$. Therefore, a group of order $10$ cannot possibly contain an element of order $4$.

Comment: Can I apply this even if G is not cyclic? I mean, is always the order of g equal to the order of the subgroup < g >?

Comment: @Maialen Yes, this is always true.

Comment: @Maialen If you have such a question, try to make an example. We have $g=(123)$ of order $3$, and yes, indeed we have $\langle g \rangle =\{(1),(123),(132)\}$ with $3$ elements. This is in $G=S_3$ and $S_3$ is not cyclic.

Comment: But other question.. If now I want to know if is there any element of order 10 in G? 10 divides the order of G which is 10, but if this was true G would be cyclic; but G is not cyclic in this case. So there is not any element of order 10 in G, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and this is essentially equivalent to $G$ not being cyclic. And $G$ not being cyclic follows of course from the fact that it is not even commutative.

Comment: But as G is generated by two elements (and not by only one element), I can say that G is not cyclic, right?

Comment: No, you just have a specific generating set with two generators. There might still be one with only one generator. Consider, for example, the cyclic group with 100 elements $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ and let $G = \langle 20, 30\rangle$. Even though I gave it as a group generated by two generators, it is still cyclic: $G = \langle 10 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z} / 100 \mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group of order $10$.